# How to indent the button?

Tags: sapui5

I have following SAPUI5 app:

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bifunctor/project/editor/XaOapY#)
```

I would like to indent the query button on the same like from input.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: What does "Payers: From To" mean? Is the "Query" button associated with the "Payers" semantically at all? Query what? What's the role of that button? I'm just making sure that we're not trying to [solve *Y* while the actual problem is *X*](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Also please, do not misuse code formatting to bypass Stack Overflow's warning "Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is kind of a hack. Just add an empty label association to the
>   button.

```
<Label text="Payers"></Label>
<Input id="payerFrom" showSuggestion="true" placeholder="From"
   required="true">
</Input>
<Input id="payerTo" showSuggestion="true" placeholder="To"
   required="true">
</Input>
<Label text=""></Label>
<Button text="Query" type="Emphasized" press="queryData">
   <layoutData>
      <layout:GridData span="XL6 L6 M6 S12"/>
   </layoutData>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indent property of GridData.
Try this out:

```
<Label text="Payers"></Label>
<Input id="payerFrom" showSuggestion="true" placeholder="From"
   required="true">
</Input>
<Input id="payerTo" showSuggestion="true" placeholder="To"
   required="true">
</Input>
<Button text="Query" type="Emphasized" press="queryData">
   <layoutData>
      <layout:GridData span="XL6 L6 M6 S12" indent="L1 M1 S0"/>
   </layoutData>
</Button>
```